# New Vanity doesn’t allow proper distance for p trap

Tags: plumbing, vanity

We are installing a new vanity & my husband said it won’t work due to the bottom shelf coming up too high. I have 0 knowledge when it comes to plumbing so maybe he’s right but I’m hoping there’s a work around. I’m attaching a picture to help.
What can we do to allow the proper distance for the P-trap? Is cutting into the vanity the only option?
[image] [image]

Comment: Can you post a picture that is more focused on the drain assembly in the wall?

Comment: Sure I’ll add that

Comment: The pictures also need to be rotated. For now it looks like the sink is getting mounted on the side of a closet. :)

Comment: It’s still not entirely clear from the pictures, but I get the feeling you could cut the wye out, glue extra pipe below and use a no-hub connection above. Maybe a real plumber could weigh in…

Comment: Sorry!! I don’t know why it rotated  when I submitted it. It does seem a little hard to tell from the pictures but I appreciate all of the suggestions!

Comment: (stupid designer furniture...) They sure don't. Wait, this was a question? Then the answer is an **oscillating multi-tool**.

Answer (score 2):

### Cut the shelf

A hole in it to permit the trap bend to be where it needs to be would appear to be adequate in this case. You may also need to cut the back of the drawer to clear the trap bend poking down through the shelf, and not use that part of the back of the drawer to store things in. You can tape or hot-glue a box into the part of the drawer that needs to remain clear for the trap to allow the drawer to open, so things don't slide in there and jam.

The Vain-ness of vanities has to be subservient to the function of the plumbing in them.

Otherwise you are looking at some expensive or difficult plumbing to move the drain entrance in the wall up.

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling that would be the case. My husband said he didn’t want to cut into it but I don’t want to go through the hassle of taking down the vanity & trying to return it.

Comment: Cut the holes super precise, or frame it out with some one-by-four sticking up so stuff doesn't get pushed and fall into under the cabinet. And that also protects the assembly from getting knocked loose. Same thing you'd have to do to the drawer if you cut a slot in the back of it. Plastic one-by is great for this. Basically, PVC exterior door case trim. Use 1x6 if that's what the drawer is. Fancy ruffled side, out (un-used), so it doesn't get dirty.